# why my last.addEventListener("click",nextLevel) not working?

Tags: javascript, function, dom, dom-events, addeventlistener

https://codepen.io/demi-chen/pen/RwGPgxv

```
 let last = theLeftSide.lastElementChild

 last.addEventListener("click",nextLevel)
 console.log(last) =====> it does show <img>......why the addEventListener not working 

 function nextLevel(){

 event.stopPropagation();
 numberOfFaces += 5;
 generateFaces();

 }
```

I try to find the lastElementChild in the first div. It does show ...... after I use console.log to check. why the addEventListener not working.  I click the lastElementChild smile.png face but it's not working. if function nextLevel() is working. the left&right side should add more smile.png.

Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its quite a simple fix really change your nextlevel to

```
function nextLevel(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  numberOfFaces += 5;
  generateFaces();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you tell me more about why put the event inside? or anything you recommend I read? thank you very much!

Comment: You have to pass the event parameter to be able to read it, window.event is a global event and not an item related event